# How to obtain access_token from google oauth2

Tags: reactjs

I want to get access_token from google oauth2 to use it to create google spreadsheet. I found below code but I want to get New token not referesh

```js
async function getNewToken(refreshToken) {
  return await fetch('https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token', {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      client_id: '<MY_CLIENT_ID>',
      client_secret: '<MY_CLIENT_SECRET>',
      refresh_token: refreshToken,
      grant_type: 'refresh_token',
    }),
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, user has to login, what will return CODE. This CODE you can exchange for access token.
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#httprest

Generally: a code will start authentication on client (browser), this will open classic Google authentication and authorization. It`s result is CODE, that you send to backend and exchange with Google for the access token.